# How to change a button's colour permanently when pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a grid, but I would like the player to be able to click on the buttons to change the colour.

I just don't have a clue, activebackground doesn't work

```
#Grid Code
grd = Tk()
grd.title ("Bryn's Random Game of Randomness")
frame = Frame(grd)
grd.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grd.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(frame, activebackground="green")
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")
frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(15)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(5)), weight=1)

grd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not use `background` instead of `activebackground`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button

def change_color(event):
    button = event.widget
    button.configure(bg="green")  # Change the background color to green

grd = Tk()
grd.title("Bryn's Random Game of Randomness")
frame = Frame(grd)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for x in range(15):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = Button(frame, bg="white")
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", change_color)  
grd.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `cycler` function that returns a function to cycle each button's color (you can of course define the color_list as you like), and used the buttons' `background` instead of `activebackground`:

```
def cycler(button):
    color_list = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow']
    def cycle():
        index = color_list.index(button['background'])
        index = (index + 1) % len(color_list)
        button['background'] = color_list[index]
    return cycle

#Grid Code
grd = Tk()
grd.title ("Bryn's Random Game of Randomness")
frame = Frame(grd)
grd.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grd.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(frame, background="green")
        btn['command'] = cycler(btn)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")
frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(15)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(5)), weight=1)

grd.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems I missed the 'permanently' if your question and made some assumptions... But anyway, you can always adapt this code to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I used it and it worked better than I thought it would, plus it solved a future problem of mine!